# show div when video is at 95% HTML5 player

Tags: html

I am trying to make a div display at 95% play time of the video, can someone help me with this?
HTML5 player

Comment: Hook into the `progress` event.

Comment: No, the *progress* event only fires as the video is being downloaded, it is not related to playback.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'timeupdate' html5 media event - http://jsfiddle.net/m3orwedL/1

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function() {

    var video_el, percentage;

    function init() {

        video_el = document.createElement('video');
        video_el.src = "http://jspro.brothercake.com/media-events/media/BadgerWatch.mp4";

        video_el.setAttribute("controls", true);
        console.log(video_el);

        video_el.addEventListener('timeupdate', checkTime); 

        document.body.appendChild(video_el);

    }

    function checkTime() {
        percentage = video_el.currentTime / video_el.duration * 100;
        console.log(Math.round(percentage) + '%');

        if(percentage >= 95) {
            alert('video is at 95%!');
            video_el.removeEventListener('timeupdate', checkTime); 

        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

}).call();
```

Comment: can't make it work with my video player, maybe i am just doing it wrong.

Comment: Hmm, Are you getting any console errors? Or are you using a special player plugin or something?

Comment: i can give you the link to my player? and maybe you could see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes please post the link!

Comment: dont think too much about title and stuff :D

Comment: There is a console error, can you fix it first? on line 64: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: `durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs;` this line? and what to do ? i must say i am new to this, and just trying to learn :)

Comment: It means exactly what it says, durtimetext is null...it should be curtimetext, not durtimetext.

Comment: Well i have now removed that line, because this line `curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs;` is just on top of it. the code you provided if you look at my code, can you that adjust it, so it will fit for me? it would be nice.

Comment: You didn't even put the code I suggested in your code...sorry I cannot make your website for you :P But I did answer your question.

Comment: and thanks for that. :) but i cant get it to work.. but thanks for your answer.